# Is there a way in android to show a textview above the imageview in a viewpager in pre-lollipop devices?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, textview

i've tried to put a textview on the imageview in a viewpager that works pretty well in lollipop and post-lollipop devices by using elevation but the textview is invisible in pre-lollipop devices. Would be grateful if i could solve it.

Comment: Please share your code...

Comment: have you tried using drawableBottom of TextView? I dont know what exactly you want to achieve but in cases where you dont need to modify the image (stretch etc) that works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can do this by using this:

```
  yourView.bringToFront();
```

But this works in RelativeLayout not in LinearLayout.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly that i needed! :)